# Access JSON data with react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a JSON in this form

"description": "{\"en\":\"some text\",\"fr\":\"un autre text\"}",

I can access the english text in this way

```
 <Cell cellTitle='test' cellDescription={JSON.parse(rowData.description).en}
```

but when I use a variable that contains the current language, it dosen't works. I tried this

```
  render() {
     const lang = I18n.locale;
    return (
<Cell cellTitle='test' cellDescription={JSON.parse(rowData.description).lang}
```

or

```
<Cell cellTitle='test' cellDescription={JSON.parse(rowData.description).{lang}}
```

none of them worked. Can you help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
render() {
  const description = JSON.parse(rowData.description);
  const lang = I18n.locale;

  return (
    <Cell cellTitle='test' cellDescription={description[lang]} ... />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but for me it dose not work without parsing the json. So the solution for me was JSON.parse(rowData.shortDescription)[currentLanguage]

Comment: I updated the answer, so if it works, you can accept it :).